# Efficient animation of time-variant drawing using CAKeyFrameAnimation

Tags: ios, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation, cashapelayer

My current goal is to animate the drawing of a picture in my iOS app so that a user could see something like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlDmk5WdaHk happening on their screen.

The acceleration of my drawings vary with time so I've built my animation using `CAKeyFrameAnimation` and `keyTimes`. At the moment, I only have one Bezier path which specifies all the points of my drawing, I add the path to my `CAShapeLayer` object, and then pass the path off to my animation object when I start my animation.

**My problem:** the completed drawing immediately appears on the screen, and my pen cursor then moves along the picture according to my `keyTimes` values, instead of having the stroke color filling in tandem with my pen cursor movement on the screen to produce the same effect as the video.

I noticed this SO question, where the recommended solution was to produce a separate path for every point in the animation: [How to Animate CoreGraphics Drawing of Shape Using CAKeyframeAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762236/how-to-animate-coregraphics-drawing-of-shape-using-cakeyframeanimation)

Given that I have 100-300 individual points, is there a more efficient method of producing a time-variant drawing, than creating an array of a couple hundred paths (with a couple hundred values in each path) with the paths in this form:

```
path0 = point0...point0...point0...point0... 
path1 = point0...point1...point1...point1...
path2 = point0...point1...point2...point2...
path3 = point0...point1...point2...point3...
```

Then taking that array of paths, passing it into `myAnimation.values` and animating `values`  with my `keyTimes`? Or is that really the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is a more efficient way if your points are on a bezier path. CAShapeLayer has two little properties called strokeStart and strokeEnd. If you initially set strokeEnd to zero then your path will not show. At 1.0 it will show completely. Increasing the values from zero to one will trace your curve accordingly. This is an animatable property so synchronize its value with the key times of your other animation and your drawing will appear as the "pen" is moving.