# Why CAKeyframeAnimation didn't present after created?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation, quartz-core

My code won't work.

```
- (CAKeyframeAnimation  *)createAnimation {
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];

    //does the @"path" mean the path I created below ? or path on some layer?

    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];


    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, width-100, 0);

    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, width+100, 300, width-100, height);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, width+20, 220, width-100, height);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, width+50, 230, width-100, height);
    // …… more code

    animation.path = path;
    animation.repeatCount = 10;
    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.duration = 2;

    CGPathRelease(path);
    return animation;
}
```

This is my animation. I have implement the delegate `animationDidStart` and `didStop`. This animation did executed.

Then I add this animation to a custom `CALayer`. I intend to animate one path on the layer. This is code for the layer:

```
 dragLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    dragLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    dragLayer.path = [self pathToAnimateWithX:0 andY:0]; // custom method to create CGPathRef
    dragLayer.fillColor = appColor.CGColor;
    dragLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor  ;
    dragLayer.lineWidth = 5;
    [self.layer addSublayer:dragLayer];

    [dragLayer addAnimation:[self createAnimation] forKey:@"uposuuuition"];
```

I thought the problem is that the animated path has no color, and I don't know how to add to it after a lot of searching (including apple's documentation).

The other problem is how to animate the dragLayer's own path instead of recreating it.

---

UPDATE: I have read the documentation again and CAKeyframeAnimation seems to be the wrong way to do it.I have find other way to do it.Thanks

Comment: @manman thanks,it moved.But I want to animate the shape of the path,no the position, how can I do that

Comment: Do you mean something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762236/how-to-animate-coregraphics-drawing-of-shape-using-cakeyframeanimation)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re trying to do? Do you need to animate a transition from one path to another, or just animate the drawing of a path as if it’s being drawn by a pen?

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon I want to create a drag animation like wave.So I need to animate the arc line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're animating the `path` property of the shape layer, but you want to animate the `position` property. Try this instead:

```
- (CAKeyframeAnimation  *)createAnimation {
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    ...
```